# Use C# Marshall.GetActiveObject to get a specific instance of the target

Tags: c#, ms-access, com

I have multiple MS Access instances open so that I can Alt-TAB to switch among them. I'm trying to connect my C# code to a specific Access instance, but the `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application")` call asks for any Access application, not a specific one.

I tried the documentation, but all the `GetActiveObject` examples use "XXX.Application" and not a specific filename or pathname.

Is there any way of connecting to a specific database? I tried using a pathname to the database, but it caused a COMException "Invalid class string" error.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;  // *MUST* have DAO as well
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access; // Access = a namespace qualifier

[TestMethod()]
  public void MsAccessComInteropTest() {
    // explicitly cast the object to an Access.Application
    var app = (Access.Application) Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
    Dprint($"{app.Name}"); // prints Microsoft Access
    Dprint($"{app.CurrentUser()}"); // prints Admin

    var db = app.CurrentDb();
    Dprint($"{db.Name}");    // this is not the database I want to connect to

}
```

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't meet the expectations (which is quite probable), there's a simple and reliable method to get the active instances of Access that doesn't require you to know the opened file path. Since Access, unlike Excel, creates a Process per database, you can use `Process.GetProcessesByName()`, then use [AccessibleObjectFromWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow) to turn each `Process.MainWindowHandle` into a COM Object that represents an `Access.Application` instance.

Comment: The `dwId` parameter is `OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0` and `riid` is the IDispatch Guid: `static Guid IDispatch = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");`, passed by `ref` to the method. `ppvObject` is the `ref` object that represents the `Access.Application` instance. If you cannot get it to work, make another question and let me know, posting a comment here.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for taking the time to help me. I learned a lot from your comments and can see now why Access is different than Word, Excel, etc. My code should figure out exactly which db it wants to use first, then get the db by inspecting window titles or by inspecting db names via `AccessibleObjectFromWindows` as you describe. Your tip on `AccessibleObjectFromWindows` can probably solve other problems for me too (I did not know about it before). It will take some time to change the design of my calling code. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw, to shorten the code, you can declare the function like this: `[DllImport("Oleacc.dll")] internal static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwId, ref Guid riid, ref Access.Application ppvObject);`, where `hWnd` is `[Process].MainWindowHAndle`. `ppvObject` returns the `Access.Application` COM Object (fully accessible in debug-mode), so you can read the database opened by that instance directly with `string dbName = [Access.Application].CurrentDB().Name`. Remember to release (Marshal) those objects.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thank you again for the help. My understanding after much reading on SO and old books is that releasing COM objects is not required because RCW runtime callable wrappers are created in managed memory space and are automatically released (albeit at the timing of the GC). If memory serves me correctly, I think @HansPassant said once that "Only <somename> got it right." The main issue is that objects you don't see also get created (and automatically released) in managed space. So manual releases alone are insufficient anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know what Hans wrote and, in general, is a good advice, also because you often don't know *what* you're releasing and what marshaling COM objects actually does. Marshaling COM objects of the Office products in more straightforward though. GC can help sometimes, with Excel more than others (since it creates COM objects when you don't ask, let's say). Access is much simpler (because of the way its instances are created). But you have to marshal the objects you create, or you'll end up chasing your tail when you create new COM objects, both from instances and internal objects.

Comment: Make a test: open 2-3 databases, then use Interop (possibly, as described here) to handle those instances through COM. When you close all the Access application (those created by opening a database file), you'll see that while your app is opened, those instances won't actually close (you can still see them in Task Manager). Similar, but worse, if you use `Mashal.ReleseComObject()` on each of the Access.Application objects you created: you won't even be able to close the Access UI, it's stuck (the database closes, not the UI).

Comment: Then try with `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject();` (for each Application COM object you created) and, after that, call `Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext();`. You'll see all the Access UI instances close nicely and disappear from Task Manager. The RCW count is now ok. This applies to all other objects: you create one, your marshal one. A little trial and error here is required, but it'll avoid some serious headache, mostly when you try to handle objects that don't exactly return the values you might expect or seem not to store or preserve properties you just set.

Comment: Wow, what a great set of comments! Thank you! And you've explained what happened to me that motivated this whole post. I ran my code both in and out of VStudio unit test. It picked up the wrong database and my Access VBA macro would not run. I shut down all Access instances, and my code was still talking to the wrong database! (I could list the tables, for example). I could see no Access windows visually or via EnumWindows and was puzzled about the zombie process. (I never thought to look in the Task Manager.) I will follow your advice and report back. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jimi, after a pile of tries, I have done as you suggested and have working code now that will not hang the Access UI (using FinalReleaseComObject and CleanupUnusedObjects). Thank you for your help. Thanks also to those who linked this question to previous answers (that I read carefully). I still don't understand when and why I must manually release and cleanup COM objects - shouldn't they be GC-released when they go out of scope? One of my books says to put my COM creations in a subroutine and then call the subroutine to force proper GC-releases when the method returns.

Comment: @Jimi, Is it correct that all COM references that I create on the stack in a method, plus the hidden ones on the stack that I know nothing about, will automatically be properly decremented in the RCW and be automatically marked for GC when the method exits. Yes? If so, then the reason that I'm doing `FinalReleaseComObject` (on each of my known objects) first, followed by `CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()` (to cleanup the hidden ones) is to free up the COM objects NOW so that the Access UI can be happily closed without hanging while my app is still open. Is that right?